# partial argument match in rhino mocks

Tags: .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

In my unit test instead of IgnoreArguments i want to use some partial matching of arguments in rhino mocks testing.
How to do that?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 16):

```
// arrange
var fooStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();

// act
fooStub.Bar("arg1", "arg2", 3);

// assert
fooStub.AssertWasCalled(
    x => x.Bar(
        Arg<string>.Is.Equal("arg1"), 
        Arg<string>.Is.Anything, 
        Arg<int>.Is.Equal(3))
);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [constraints](http://www.ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Constraints.ashx). You ignore the arguments passed into the expectation call and then add explicit constraints for each argument. An example from the Rhino Mocks documentation:

```
Expect.Call(view.Ask(null,null)).IgnoreArguments().Constraints(
   Is.Anything(), 
   Is.TypeOf(typeof(SomeType))).Return(null);
```